# Binding Concrete types (using Inheritance) to a ListView and display in Hierarchical structure ASP.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, binding, hierarchical-data

I would like to bind more than two different implementations of a class to a ListView and display the data in a Hierarchical structure (multi level).

Look at the Code below to understand where I'm coming from:

Thanks in advance
M.

```
 
public class AutoElements : CommonElements
    {
       public class results_dataset
         {
            public List claimsHistory { get; set; }
          }      
        public class Claims_history
        {
            public List claim { get; set; }
            public typesectionEnum type; // attribute 
        }

        public class Claim : ClaimType
        {
            public string first_payment_date { get; set; }
            public ClaimAssociationIndicatorEnum claim_association_indicator;
            public List vehicle; 
        }

    }
```

```
 public  class CommonElements : CPRulesCommonElements 
  {
     public class ClaimType
        {
            public string  claim_date { get; set; }
            public List address { get; set; }
        }

 public class SubjectType  : BaseSubjectType
      {
        public int unit_number {get; set;}
          .....       
      }
    public class BaseSubjectType
    {
        public List driversLicense { get; set; }
          ...
     }
 public class DriversLicenseType : CPdriversLicenseType 
    {
       public LenientDateType issue_date { get; set; }
        .....
    }
}
```

```
   public class CPRulesCommonElements : Enums

    {
       public class telephoneType
        {
            public TelephoneTypeEnum type { get; set; }
            ......        }
        public class driversLicenseType
        {
            public DriversLicenseHistoryEnum history { get; set; }
             ......        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary data structure from your classes and bind to that?

Comment: Irish, Could you please provide me an example. Thanks

Comment: How are accessing the data for these classes initially?

Comment: My source is an XML file. I am using LINQ to XML to fetch the data from XML file and hold it in the classes.